# How to pass JSF param's value as method parameter?

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2, param, method-parameters

Now, customerCaseController.customerCase.caseId is a string of numbers and is working if I just print it on the xhtml page as a heading or label.

I'd like to call the method `findByCustomerCase(String caseId)` in my `fileAttachmentController` but this isn't working:

```
   <f:param customerCase="#{customerCaseController.customerCase.caseId}" />
    <p:dataTable var="fileAttachment" 
    value="#{fileAttachmentController.findByCustomerCase(customerCase)}">

   ...table-contents...

   </p:dataTable>
```

That would just pass the text "customerCase" as parameter to the method findByCustomerCase and not the value of the param customerCase. How can I pass the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `f:param` the wrong way. This element is not used to define a local variable. This means that `customerCase` is not a valid variable at that point.

You are accessing `customerCaseController.customerCase.caseId`and not just `customerCase`, so you need to pass exactly the same as argument aswell and skip the whole `f:param`.

Change your code to the following to get access to the desired `caseId`:

```
<p:dataTable var="fileAttachment" 
 value="#{fileAttachmentController.findByCustomerCase(customerCaseController.customerCase.caseId)}">

...table-contents...

</p:dataTable>
```

---

In case you would like to keep the way of holding a local variable consider the following instead of `f:param`:

```
<ui:param name="customerCase" value="#{customerCaseController.customerCase.caseId}" />
```

XML-Namespace: `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`

This will allow you to use your code from above. Just replace `f:param` with this snippet.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I guess I'm just not used to the xhtml side of things yet. +1 for bringing up the ui:param.